# How many Master Seals are in the game?

Tags: fire-emblem-warriors

Upon reading the description of the master seal it appears there is a limited amount of them in game. My question is how rare are they actually? Is there enough to promote mostly every unit? Will I run out and then unlock my favorite hero and never be able to promote them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, from the story mode and history mode combined, there are currently enough Master Seals to upgrade every character that is available, and when the DLC is released, they will include more Master Seals for the new heroes in the new history mode maps.

While the story mode seals are relatively easy to get, the history mode missions require an S ranking on maps that may be difficult, so be sure to diversify the types of heroes that you use the seals on (swords, axes, lances, etc.) so you have a good choice of powered-up warriors when trying to get the others.

Comment: I wish I could add another upvote for mentioning to keep the classes diverse when promoting. The Weapon Triangle is crucial in the FE series

Comment: Not so much in Warriors. A high level or popping awakening mode throws the triangle out the window ;)

Comment: @Rapitor Haven’t played Warriors yet, so I wasn’t aware of that :)

Comment: For such a crucial mechanic, it doesn't really matter too much in Warriors. Chrom and Xander can easily get through enemy soldiers and even Generals as long as you constantly attack.

Comment: They removed the crucialness(?) of the triangle mainly because over half the cast is sword users... and its a warriors game first, fire emblem second.